# Dynamic Arrow coming out undefined when CANVAS used to make a line and an arrow

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im making an arrow using a `drawArrow` function I made where I have an array with coordinates and I loop through it using a slider that returns values.

The function is just made so lines are draw than returns an arrow.

Something like this: `<--->;`

`< >` are the arrow heads and the dashed lines are just a line.

As the slider changes I use `clearrect` and then the line and arrows get redrawn depending on the coordinates.

My problem is that I need those arrows/line to have a shadow effect and Im using a buffer canvas so that the shadow effect on the arrow doesnt overlap on the line. The problem is that with this method I get an undefined picture (undefined as in bad def).

Im not sure how to fix this, any recommendations?

I didnt post any code b/c its just a combination of .move to, lineto with a slider returning values and an array with coordinates.

Comment: Can you post an image or HTML. Anything would be helpful, since it is difficult to envision what you want

Comment: fixed lol..thanks though

Comment: not fixed yet : provide some code since the devil is in the details.